# checkbox in php with switch statement

Tags: php, html, forms

Why deos it return 2 when I check both checkboxes? How can I return a different response when both checkboxes are turn on?

html:

```
<form action="form3.php" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
  <legend> select your team </legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="punto3" value="1"> 1 </input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="punto3" value="2"> 2 </input>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>       
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['punto3']))
{
    $punto3 = $_REQUEST['punto3'];

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "progetto2");
    if ($conn == false)
    {
    die("fail: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    switch ($punto3)
    {
    case '1': // 1 checkbox
    break;
    case '2': // 2 checkbox
    break;
    default: // if 1 and 2 is both checked
    }
} else {
    echo "Please, do at least one selection";
}
?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Using the same attribute name will get whatever the last value may be. Change `name="punto3"` => `name="punto3[]"`. The handling will need changing to work with the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use separate name attribute values for each checkbox and use if conditions instead of a switch (or use the radio button if you have required only one value) example:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="form3.php" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
  <legend> select your team </legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="punto3_1" value="1"> 1 </input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="punto3_2" value="2"> 2 </input>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>       
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if (
      (isset($_REQUEST['punto3_1']) && $_REQUEST['punto3_1'] != "")
      || (isset($_REQUEST['punto3_2']) && $_REQUEST['punto3_2'] != "")

)
{
    $punto3_1 = $_REQUEST['punto3_1'];
    $punto3_2 = $_REQUEST['punto3_2'];

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "progetto2");
    if ($conn == false)
    {
    die("fail: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['punto3_1']) && $_REQUEST['punto3_1'] != ""){
        //your logic for punto3_1 will goes here....
    } elseif(isset($_REQUEST['punto3_2']) && $_REQUEST['punto3_2'] != ""){
        //your logic for punto3_2 will goes here....
    } else {
       //your logic for punto3_1 and punto3_2 will goes here....
    }
} else {
    echo "Please, do at least one selection";
}
?>
```